# MaxSubArray using dynamic style

Tags: scala, substring

I have been trying to create code that counts the max substring from array and returns sum and starting and ending point. I have some error in there however that I cannot spot because for example when I use `Array(-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4)` as source I get return `(7, 5,8)`. However, the correct answer should be `(6, 3, 6)`. Code below.

```
 def solve(a: Array[Int]): (Int, Int, Int) = {
    require(a.nonEmpty)

    val n = a.length
    val temp = Array.fill(n)(0, 0, 0)
    var max = (0,0,0)                      // sum, start, end

    for (i <- 0 to n-1) {
      temp(i) = (a(i), i, i)
    }

    for (i <- 0 to n-1) {
      for (j <- 0 to i) {
        if (a(i) > a(j) && temp(i)._1 < temp (j)._1 + a(i)) {
          temp(i) = (temp(j)._1 + a(i), j, i) 
        }
      }
    }
    for (i <- 0 to n-1){
      if (max._1 < temp(i)._1){
        max = temp(i)     
      }
    }
    return max

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a more Scala/functional approach?

```
  def solve(a: Array[Int]): (Int, Int, Int) = {
    a.tails.zipWithIndex.flatMap{
      case (arr, ti) =>
        arr.inits.map{
          tail => (tail.sum, ti, ti + tail.length -1)
        }
    }.maxBy(_._1)
  }

solve (Array(-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4)) => res7: (Int, Int, Int) = (6,3,6)
```

Comment: Isn't your solution at least cubic?

Comment: I didn't try to optimise it, only to express the solution in a directly fuctional fashion. In fact @jwvh 's solution above is the same complexity, we both generate the same O(n^2) number of subsequences and sum each independently.
There are plenty of optimisation points you could add here, but it helps to start by getting the right answer.

Comment: Getting the right answer is absolutely trivial. Getting the right answer in O(n) time is what this problem is about. O(n^2) is the starting point you can think about optimising, anything worse than that might as well go straight to /dev/null.

Comment: Ok I see OP is doing the same amount of work. I don't think it's an excuse to replicate this complexity though.